# Attribute "titleTextColor" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-dependencies

I have a gradle dependencies.
When I add **compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6'**
I get error after gradle sync. => Attribute "titleTextColor" already defined with incompatible format.

Do you have someone with that experience?

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 29
    versionName "2.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

...

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.3.3'
    compile 'eu.inmite.android.lib:android-styled-dialogs:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.5l@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be it all right if you updated your Android SDK and gradle version?

Comment: I have **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'**

Comment: and SDK version? I suppose it's 22?

Comment: `    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 29
        versionName "2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    } `

Answer (score 0):

The `com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6` has this dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

Since it is using the v24 you have to use `compileSdkVersion 24` and you should use the same level in your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated gradle file. You can see here: http://pastebin.com/atGPm0cc But nothing changed. Can I ask you about check my gradle file?